# directional derivative using grad

Tags: vector-analysis

Calculate directional derivative 0f $\phi$ at the point $Q$ in the given direction:

$\phi=\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, $Q(a,b,c)$; towards the origin.

I firstly need to find $\operatorname{grad}\phi=\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}(x\mathfrak{i}+y\mathfrak{j}+z\mathfrak{k})$

Then I replace the point $q$ in $\operatorname{grad}\phi$. Then, I do not know how to proceed with the origin.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you know the right definition of directional derivative. Just note that, here we need a unit vector preferably. So, as the exercise wanted use the following unit vector $$\vec{u}=\frac{\vec{QO}}{|\vec{QO}|}$$

Comment: Dear Severus Snape, it is the first time I am dealing with these things, is it possible for you to give some more hints.

Comment: Exercise called for a vector from $Q|_{(a,b,c)}$ toward origin $O|_{(0,0,0)}$ so we have $\vec{QO}=(0-a,0-b,0-c)=(-a,-b,-c)$. Lets to normalize $\vec{QO}$ by doing $\frac{\vec{QO}}{|\vec{QO}|}$.

Comment: So we get a unit vector as $$\vec{u}=\left(\frac{-a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\frac{-c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right)$$

Comment: Now, use the defenition. :-)

Comment: Getting to see some light in this. Thank you, by the way, I like the name severus snape <3.

Comment: @Toshina11: You'r welcome! :-)